# php in_array confusion: the strict setting

Tags: php, types

I've struggled with the php in_array() function all morning. Eventually I was able to fix it but I'm a bit confused about why the setting fixed the problem.

I set the variable $type to a string value('forum' to be exact), and the $all_types to an array looking like this:

$all_types:

```
[protocol2] => protocol2
[group] => 0
[post] => 0
[forum] => 0
[article] => 0
[page] => 0
[protocol1] => 0
```

And then I had:

```
if (in_array($type,$all_types) !== FALSE) {
  "Do stuff..."
}
```

And "Do stuff..." kept happening. First I thought it was because it hit on the 'forum' key in the array so I tried changing the array to:

```
[0] => protocol2
[1] => 0
[2] => 0
[3] => 0
[4] => 0
[5] => 0
[6] => 0
```

But it still didn't work. Finally I set the STRICT variable to TRUE and it seems to work fine, even with the original array.

So why is this? STRICT = TRUE meant the needle and the value in the haystack had to be of the same type, but aren't they both strings when they do match? And when they don't you compare 'forum' to 0, and does that for some reason match?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A problem about in_array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476878/a-problem-about-in-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). When you using 'STRICT' as FALSE, in_array compares values ​​using '==' operator.
And you know, `var_dump('string' == 0);` is true.

So, when you have different types of values ​​in an array, it's always good to compare it with strict comparison.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Why is `'string' == 0`? I thought 0, empty string and null are `false`, while non-empty strings numbers != 0 are `true`

Comment: var_dump('string' == 0); is indeed TRUE. But why ?

Comment: @Laxus: Ok, so the answer is: the value of $type is converted into a float, and since its content does not read like a valid numerical value it is set to the value of zero (0). That value is compared.

Comment: @arkascha  If you compare a number with a string, the string is converted to a number and the comparison will be numerically

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected when you change the value of $type. As you imply in your question, type juggling makes unexpected things happen, so stick to strict.

```
<?php
$type      = 'forum';
$all_types = array(
    'protocol2' => 'forum',
    'group' => 0,
    'post' => 0,
    '1' => '0',
    'article' => 0,
    'page' => 0,
    'protocol1' => 0
);

if (in_array($type, $all_types, TRUE)) {
    echo "Here";
} else {
    echo "Not Here";
}
```

Comment: Hang on. Backtracking... I had a typo. I'll keep playing.

Comment: I did the same, but this is not an answer. He asked about WHY things are this way.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you should use array_key_exists - as you are testing for array keys and not for values (this is what in_array does).

Comment: No, read the question again. He is trying to mathc the values, not the keys.

Comment: I am not testing for the array keys.