# Checking session array for value (PHP in_array)

Tags: php, arrays, session

My simple shopping cart stores products id's in a session array.

I'm trying to set up an if/else statement to enable/disable my "Add to cart" button based on the product ID being in array or not.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Show cart array

print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
echo '<br><br>';

//Return "yes" or "no"

$panier = $_SESSION['cart'];
$produit = "5";

if (in_array($produit, $panier)) {
print "yes man!";
} 
else {
print "no man!";
}

?>
```

I'm making sure 5 is part of the array values by displaying them of this test page, but the second part always returns "no man!"

looks simple enough to me. What am i doing wrong ?

print_r command output is

```
5,5

no man!
```

that is because i've added 2 of the "5" product id to my cart

If I change this line

```
 print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

for

```
 print_r($_SESSION);
```

I get

```
 Array ( [cart] => 5,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2 )

 no man!
```

Comment: Show the output of `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);`

Comment: `print_r` can't output `5,5`, it should give output similar to `Array(cart => Array([0] => 5 [1] => 5))`. However, if it really does give `5,5`, then it means you put it in a string and that's why `in_array` doesn't work. And please do not post updates to your questions as answers - rather post it as comment or update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, according to you, `$_SESSION['cart'] = "5,5";` and it means it is a string. So the right code to look up your value is `strpos()`:

```
$pos = strpos($produit, $_SESSION['cart']);
if($pos !== false) {
    echo "YES";
}
else {
    echo "NO";
}
```

**BUT** there's a huge risk to get the wrong answer for this. Imagine, you have two products in your cart - first with id 15 and the other with id 7. You'll be looking for id 5. What would the above code output? It will output "YES".

So, instead of using a string, I suggest you use multidimensional array (if you want to stick with sessions). In this particular case then, the variable `$_SESSION["cart"]` would be an array and with adding new products it would look like this:

```
$_SESSION["cart"] = array(); // initial value, don't call it every time or it'll flush your array
$_SESSION["cart"][] = $product_ID;
```

Or similar to it.

`print_r` will give you a similarly-looking output:

```
Array(
    cart => array(
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 17
        [2] => 5
    )
)
```

Then, `in_array` should work. But, plan your storing wisely ;)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, According to what the script returns after my changes i guess i'm really having an array in there. Isn't there any other way to check for my value in it that would not require my to change the way I write $_SESSION ? This would be a pain!

Comment: @FélixDesmeules you are wrong, according to your output, you got a string in `$_SESSION['cart']`, not an array. An easier way? Well, there always is a way and you can store variables however you want. But in time as your code grows bigger, you __will__ come to conclusion that it's a wrong way, trust me. So better rewrite it now than later ;)

Comment: Then my problem is everything currently works with strings, altough i'm sure you are right about the rewrite part, I will have to go this way for now. could I change the string to an array on this code ?

Comment: @FélixDesmeules if you want to keep strings, then store product ids in unique separators, for example [], so the string would look like `$_SESSION['cart'] = "[5][3][3][5][5][17]";` and when you look for `$produit`, wrap it around in `[` and `]`. In this case you will not be getting wrong answers in case you searh for `5` in a string of `15,7,2`.

Answer (score 0):

As jon asked it is better put always the output of your program But for now I am suspecting your problem is in the in_array check this link [A problem about in_array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476878/a-problem-about-in-array) it might help

Comment: Your post does not answer the question completely, so in future please don't post it as answer, but as a comment under the question.

Comment: Got it, following are upcoming answers. Thanks

Comment: @Nordenheim They don't have the rep to put a comment.